# A question relating trigonometric integrals with gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Why is it that $$\int _0 ^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin^m (x)\cos^n(x) =\frac {\gamma\left(\frac {m+1}{2}\right).\gamma \left(\frac {n+1}{2}\right)}{\gamma \left(\frac {m+n+2}{2}\right)} $$. How is it proved. Further my professor added that its true only for integers $m,n $. Why so? Also he said that it was only for this specific form and not for any other like where you have argument of sine,cosine as $2x $. I know we can substitute $2x=u $ and then continue but why cant we carry on with the same $2x $ as we do it for $x $. Is it associated with period of $\sin,\cos$. Thanks!

Comment: This is a beta-function identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: i think in this form is your result not correct, there must be conditions for $m,n$

Comment: I have written that m,n are integers.I want to know why it isnt true for any m,n in real

Comment: Your identity is incorrect for $m=1$ and $n=1$:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\cos(x)~dx=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(2)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$
$$1\neq \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Using the definition of the beta function:
$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}~dt$$
And substituting $t=\cos^2{\theta}$, I obtain:
$$B(x,y)=2\int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos{\theta})^{2x-1}(\sin{\theta})^{2y-1}~d\theta$$
Then substituting $m=2x-1$ and $n=2y-1$, I obtain:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^m{\theta}\sin^n{\theta}~d\theta=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\color{red}{2}\cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{m+n+2}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: See also [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 3):

Your prof is not correct. It is defined for some real values. Also your notation is used for Incomplete gamma function.

Start by

$$\int^1_0 t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1}\,dt = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Let $t = \sin^2 \theta$

$$2\int^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^{2x-1}(\theta) \cos^{2y-1}(\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

This is defined for $\Re \, x , y > 0$. You can let $2x-1 = n,2y-1 =m$.

For instace we have $x=3/4,y=1/2$

$$\int^{\pi/2}_0 \sqrt{\sin \theta}\, d\theta = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\Gamma^2\left(\frac{3}{4} \right)$$

We can also prove the somewhat similar identity

$$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos(x \theta)\cos^y(\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{\pi \Gamma(y+1)}{2^{y+1}\Gamma\left(\frac{x+y+2}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2-x+y}{2}\right)}$$

using [contour integration](http://advancedintegrals.com/2017/04/integrating-a-function-around-three-branches-using-a-semi-circle-contour/).